# Linear maps defined on pure tensors is well defined.

Tags: linear-transformations, tensor-products

Suppose $V_1, \ldots, V_k, W$ are vector spaces, and suppose we define a map $f:V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_k \to W$ by sending pure tensor elements $v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k$ to $f(v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k)$ . Now because any elements of $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$ can be written as the sum of pure tensors we can extend $f$ linearly on whole of $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$.

How to show that $f$ is well defined? I know that any elements of $V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$ can be written as a sum of pure tensors but it is not unique right? An element of $V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$ might have different representation as sums of pure tensors, in that case $f$ might not be well defined, but the books I'm reading always define maps this way. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(e_j^k)_j$ be bases. The map $f': V_1 \times \cdots \times V_k \to W$ induced by sending $(e_{j_1}^1, \cdots, e_{j_k}^k)$ to $f(e_{j_1}^1 \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{j_k}^k)$ is well defined because $(e_j^1)_j \times \cdots \times (e_j^k)_j$ is a basis of $V_1 \times \cdots \times V_k$. It follows from the universal property of the tensor product that this extends uniquely to a map $f: V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_k \to W$ which sends $e_{j_1}^1 \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{j_k}^k$ to $f(e_{j_1}^1 \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{j_k}^k)$.

You do mean $v_j$ are basis elements right? Otherwise the statement is false, if you send $v_1 \otimes v_2$ to $a$ and $w_1 \otimes v_2$ to $b$, you must send $(v_1 + w_1) \otimes v_2$ to $a + b$, so you do not have freedom to define $f$ however you want on all pure tensors, just on tensors of basis elements.

Comment: In  my context, $v_j$ are not basis elements.

Comment: @Uncool Then $f$ may not be well defined, for example when you take $a, b = 1$ and define $f((v_1 + w_1) \otimes v_2) = 3$.

Comment: @Uncool Are you sure you don't have a collection of maps $f_j: V_j \to W_j$ which induce a unique map $f_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes f_k \to W_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes W_k$? In that case there does exist a unique map which sends $v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k$ to $f_1(v_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes f_k(v_k)$ by universal property and $(f_1, \cdots, f_k)$ being multilinear.

Comment: Ok thankyou. I might have been wrong all this time